# Wordpress:Custom banner from psd trying to cut out a button area so the website link can be clicable not working

Tags: plugins

[1
please zoom into the image and you will se greyed out area this is where the button is on header of the site, the button when i place mouse over it am unable to click it due to this image being on the way.
because its an image even though its png transperant in middle the website still sees the whole image as 1 element and this is why the website button under it can be seen but not clicked

Comment: You might be able to fix this with z-index: make sure the button that needs to be clicked is on top of the banner? Or you could add a click handler to the banner that identifies which pixels belong to the button and pass the click event on, but that sounds more fiddly to me.

Comment: i chopped the image into 2 pieces and the button area is cleared,i understand that even if image is transparent around the button it will not click. i have one problem now that i fixed the banner for desktop if i go view it on mobile the banner looks huge how do i go around fixing that